# data is not displaying in html form

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

am trying to display data using Asp.net api in an ionic app..its takeing values from the server but its not dispalying here is my `controller`

```
exampleApp.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.getData = function() {
    $http.get('api/product', { params: { "username": "value1", "password": "value2" } })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.username = data.username;
            $scope.password = data.password;
        })
        .error(function(data) 
            alert("ERROR");
        });
}
```

and here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body ng-app="starter">
   <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <button class="button" ng-click="getData()">click</button>
        <br> username:{{username}} {{password}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

can anyone tell where am wrong, or am i missing something..?
thanx in advance

Comment: post the complete html

Comment: try, `$scope.$apply()` inside your getData function.

Comment: Are you getting the data from the call? Did you tried to log the data?

Comment: yes am getting the data @hunzaboy

Comment: Did you tried $scope.$apply?

Comment: Is the function `getData()` called when you click the button? And the value is logged when you do `consoloe.log( $scope.username)` ?

Comment: @hunzaboy - Why do you think `$scope.$apply()` will work? You use that when the data comes in from some source outside the realm of Angularjs, like jQuery. In this case, its a normal $http call

Comment: use `then` instead of `success` and try

Comment: `$http.get('api/product', { })       .then(function(data) {`

Comment: @Edison try setting up $scope.username = "dummy text" outside the function call and see if it is showing or not